# How to check return value of mail() using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im getting success from Ajax but not receiving the intended email and there does not seem to be anything wrong with the PHP. I have little experience with PHP, I need some way to get some feedback from the PHP.

Jquery

```
   function PHP_EMAIL(name, email, message){
        var emailInfo = [name,email,message];    
        $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url:"the_php_file.php",
          data: {email_info_array: emailInfo},
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data); <---alerts the entire php script back
            alert("Email was successfuly sent!); <<<--- alerts success!
                                                        but no email recieved
          }
       });  
    }
```

PHP

```
$email_info = json_decode($_POST['email_info_array']);
$to = "my_email@gmail.com";

$subject = 'portfolio contact';
$user_name = $email_info[0];
$user_email = $email_info[1];
$message = $email_info[2];
$headers = "From: website.com";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
 echo "sent";
}
else 
{
 echo "fail";
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="site-contact-box site-text-20 site-text-grey-violet">

                       <!-- form -->
                       <form onsubmit="return false" id="emailform">

                           <div class="site-form-error">* You must fill all fields of the form  *</div>


                            <br> Name <input type="text" name="name" value="" required> <div class="site-name-error site-text-12"> * invalid name </div>
                            <br> E-mail <input type="text" name="email" value="john.doe@example.com" required> <div class="site-email-error site-text-12"> * invalid email  </div>

                            <br>
                             <div class="site-message-error site-text-12"> * message must be more than (8 characters)  </div>
                            <br> <br> please leave a message...

                            <br> <p class="site-text-12"> (minimum 8 characters) <p>

                                <br>
                            <textarea rows="12" cols="50" name="message" form="emailform" required></textarea> 

                            <br>
                            <div class="site-agree-error site-text-12"> you must agree to terms  </div>
                            <br> <br>
                            <div class="site-agreement site-text-13 site-text-black">
                               * I agree to the <a href="#">Terms & Agreement</a> <input type="checkbox" id="agree" required>
                            </div>

                           <br>   
                           <input class="site-text-bold site-text-15" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkInput()">
                       </form>
                   </div>
```

Comment: what does your html form look like ?

Comment: form that calls javascript functions using onclick() , the javascript functions check input then direct data to php as seen above

Comment: what is the html output of the form ? beside that, any error in console ? in php ?

Comment: just no results in the html, that is why im trying to get feedback from my php. i tried using success: function(data) { alert (data)} to determine mail() return value but i just get the entire php script printed ...so maybe the php is not executing?

Comment: check your print_r($email_info) you get value or not

Comment: @OldPadawan forgot about the console (not much of a web programmer) no results in the console either.

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha , the problem is i do not know how to print any of the PHP variables.

Comment: well... we can't see the form (inputs ? names ? IDs ? values ?) and how it's formatted/handled, and no console or error... I wonder why asking is like pulling teeth... **If PHP can't handle the vars, it's maybe because there are no vars or wrong ones**

Comment: check your browser  inspect element -> network -> XHR

Comment: check after click your submit button your page the_php_file.php call or not.

Comment: @OldPadawan , whether or not the vars are incorrect it should still be sending an email to me. ill post the form and ill try swapping first $to arg in mail() to a string literal of the email.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php    
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);?>

query succeed or not.   
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';  
    }else {
        $response_array['status'] = 'error';  
    }

On the client side:

    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'success'){
            alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
        }else if(data.status == 'error'){
            alert("Error on query!");
        }
    },
```

Comment: im new to PHP, what exactly is data?

Comment: question is about sending email, not making a database query. This is just some random generic example you've cut and pasted. Also IMO in an AJAX API if the DB call fails you should return a HTTP status error, not just a string and pretend the request was successful.